# How to get values from custom module to widget

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have a custom module that generate some custom values like **quantity**, **Order** total i need to get those values in **custom widget** .

**Is there any standard way to achieve this?**

Comment: Standard way is to add block in your widget and get all the values in this block ... Can you Explain What you actually want with your written code so far..